# Is it permissible to accept personal incentives from medical companies to buy their products through my work?

Tags: halal-haram, work

I'm working in a hospital, and my duty is to give orders of medicines to the medicine company.  My problem is that many companies have the same medicine which I need in the hospital, so all medicine company owner wants that I give order to them, and I'm a fully authorised person to give orders to the company which I choose.

All medicine company owners give same benefits to the hospital, but in parallel they want to give some gifts to me.  Of course, they profit from my side as maybe I'll give the order to them, as I'm authorised for giving whomever I want to.

I'm confused so I always refused to take it.

Is it permissible to accept personal incentives from medical companies to buy their products through my work?

Answer (score -1):

Rashwa (bribe) taking and giving is Haram.

Check your company policy if this is considered as bribe then its Haram.

And if your company does not have a bribe policy，then bribe is something you take over your salary for giving treatment/service to someone above another which will make you give the contract to company A because his gifts were more to you.

Be careful about it...